# SQLite DatabaseError: Execution ': near "(": syntax error

Tags: sqlite

Help Please, try to solve the problem in SQLite but getting that error:

```
DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql '
```

```
with df as (
select  i1.Customerid, t.milliseconds, Rank() over(partition by i1.Customerid 
                                                    order by t.milliseconds asc) as Rank
from invoices i1, invoice_items i2, tracks t
where i1.invoiceid = i2.InvoiceLineId
and i2.TrackId = t.TrackId) 
select Customerid, milliseconds
from df
where Rank < 5

having count(*) > 5;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using an old version of Sqlite that doesn't support window functions. You need 3.25 or newer.